# my non numeric columns are deleted on resample

Tags: python, pandas

My 2 non numeric columns lable and FID are deleted on resample, how to  keep those columns ?

```
T               CP      LC      DP     VB   WP      LABEL   FID
10/26/201711:00 251.05  40.9    3157.9  0   256.27  F30d    MN-0001-2017-1
10/26/201711:01 250.88  38.8    3159.3  0   257.32  F30d    MN-0001-2017-1
10/26/201711:02 250.85  38.2    3157.2  0   256.81  F30d    MN-0001-2017-1
10/26/201711:03 250.72  31.7    3159.7  0   255.74  F30d    MN-0001-2017-1
```

Using `groupby` seems only keep 1 column :

```
newseries1 = newseries.groupby('LABEL').resample('10min', level=1).mean()
newseries1.head(10)
```

I want to keep my 2 colums LABEL and FID in my dataframe

Comment: seems i got the clue by this code : newseries1 = newseries.groupby([newseries.LABEL,newseries.FID]).resample('10min', level=1).mean()

Comment: If 'LABEL' and your other non-numeric columns are 1 to 1 relationship, then yes you can include them in the groupby without changing the groups.  However, if you have more than one non-numeric value associated with a 'LABEL' then you must chooste some sort of aggregration on that non-numeric.  Such as using the first value or mode.

Answer (score 5):

`resample` is just like `groupby` so you could specify a dictionary to aggregate the numeric and non-numeric columns differenly.

```
numeric = df.select_dtypes('number').columns
non_num = df.columns.difference(numeric)
d = {**{x: 'mean' for x in numeric}, **{x: 'first' for x in non_num}}

df.resample('10min').agg(d)
```

---

Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq='3min', periods=20),
                  data={'col1': np.random.randint(1, 100, 20),
                        'col2': np.random.choice(list('abcde'), 20)})

numeric = df.select_dtypes('number').columns
non_num = df.columns.difference(numeric)
d = {**{x: 'mean' for x in numeric}, **{x: 'first' for x in non_num}}

df.resample('10min').agg(d)

#                          col1 col2
#2010-01-01 00:00:00  45.750000    e
#2010-01-01 00:10:00  61.000000    d
#2010-01-01 00:20:00  81.000000    b
#2010-01-01 00:30:00  28.750000    e
#2010-01-01 00:40:00  37.333333    a
#2010-01-01 00:50:00  20.333333    a
```

Comment: Nice. dictionary unpacking there. +1